# How does WebEx addin knows that it's a WebEx Appointment it's updating in Outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, webex

When I Cancel or Modify an Appointment in Outlook, how does WebEx knows that it's a WebEx meeting?

- Does it use event handlers on all AppointmentItems and check for the
  WebEx footer?
- Or is there a flag or property set on the
  AppointmentItem? (Which I don't think, at least not without extending
  the AppointmentItem:
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn320241.aspx)

What I'm looking to do:
We have our own server where we store our AppointmentItems and we can now create an Appointment but I would like to be able to update the server when the user updates or deletes the appointment from his calendar. So I need to know when it's an appointment created using our AddIn, we must update the server with the changes and ignore if the Appointment is created using any other program or locally in Outlook.

Comment: Take a look at a WebEx appointment in Outlook using OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) - click IMessage button. Do you see any differences with the other appointments (message class, some of the named properties)?

Comment: Thanks, I can't find any differences (which _probably_ means they use the footer as the identifier) and OutlookSpy was awesome.